# Quick Action: You can't perform this action on this page

Tags: permissions, error, quickaction, authorization

Since Spring22 upgrade, a strange behaviour has been observed and despite our investigation, we have not found the solution yet.

When we click on a custom Quick Action on some Accounts (and only on some accounts, not all of them) , we have the red error message **You can't perform this action on this page**

[image]

[image]

The Quick Action button appears well (*new Devis*), and its definition is the following

[image]
[image]

On other accounts, with the same user, the same quick action button works (create Opportunity dialog layout is opened without error message).

Those other Accounts have:

- same record Owner
- same Record Type

Other info:

- User with problem has all the righs on Account, Opportunity and related record types
- With a System Administrator user, there is no error with this account.
- There is no entry to investigate in apex debug logs
- Spring22 destroyed some rights on Permission Sets, so maybe the error is related to a removal of a right on a PS (but which one ?)
- Sharing Settings on Account/Contact is private
  [image]
- There are no custom Sharing rules defined

Comment: does the user have access to the relevant lookup fields on Account that are being copied over?  A way to debug this is create a second quickaction with the fewest fields,see if that works, and then add in fields 1x1 until it fails

Comment: can you check if you can perform the other action i.e. update or create action?

Comment: @cropredy the same QuickAction works with the same user on another Account, meaning that its has access to the lookup fields

Comment: I meant access to the lookup records.  I still think you should clone this QuickAction to a bare minimum that works and then add back fields 1x1 until it fails